# to_dict() function makes a list from dataframe instead of OrderedDict

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a dataframe into an OrderedDict.
I tried with the 2 options shown below. None of them result an OrderedDict and I don't know why it doesn't work.

Option 1 and 2 result to be lists

```
sales_data = pd.read_csv ("data/sales-data.csv")
Motorcycles = sales_data.loc[sales_data['PRODUCTLINE'] == 'Motorcycles']
Motorcycles = Motorcycles.sort_values('ORDERID').head(100)

# Option 1
Dict_Motorcycles = Motorcycles.to_dict(into=OrderedDict, orient='records')
type(Dict_Motorcycles)

# Opction 2
a= Motorcycles.to_dict('records')
type(a)
```

If I write the code `Motorcycles.to_dict('records')` it becomes and OrderedDict, but I'm not able to save it in a variable.

If I change from `orient = 'records'` to ```orient = 'index'`` it is fitted, but it is not shown in the way I want.

Comment: What do you mean about `I'm not able to save it`?

Comment: @PauloMarques I mean, I want to save an OrderedDict in a variable, i.e. ```Dict_Motorcycles ``` or ```a``` in options 1 or 2. I eddited my question to avoid misunderstundings

Answer (score 1):

Your output is a list containing a dictionary.  You can just take its zero index:

```
a= Motorcycles.to_dict('records')
print(a)
print(type(a[0]))

#sample output:
[{'ORDERID': 3, 'PRODUCTLINE': 'Motorcycles', 'SAlE': 10000}, {'ORDERID': 5, 'PRODUCTLINE': 'Motorcycles', 'SAlE': 5000}, {'ORDERID': 7, 'PRODUCTLINE': 'Motorcycles', 'SAlE': 12000}]
<class 'dict'>
```

Comment: then, this is a list as its main type. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. But the type of the item inside the list is dict as shown above.

Comment: You can eliminate 'records' and just say a= Motorcycles.to_dict(). This would give you the desired dictionary and, in Python 3.7, this would preserve the sorted order you achieved in the previous lines.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment

### Creating a test dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": ["a","b","c"]})
```

### Printing dataframe

```
>>> print(df)
   A  B
0  1  a
1  2  b
2  3  c
```

### Associating to_dict result to a variable

```
ndf = df.to_dict(into=OrderedDict, orient='records')

print(ndf)
[OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 'a')]), OrderedDict([('A', 2), ('B', 'b')]), OrderedDict([('A', 3), ('B', 'c')])]

print(type(ndf))
<class 'list'>
```

**Note** The `ndf` type is a `list` because the orient parameter is 'records'

However, if you remove the orient parameter, you will get

```
ndf = df.to_dict(into=OrderedDict)

print(ndf)
OrderedDict([('A', OrderedDict([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)])), ('B', OrderedDict([(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]))])

print(type(ndf))
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
```

**Update Mar 18th, 2021**

If you really need an OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ndf = OrderedDict({ "myDataFrame": df.to_dict(into=OrderedDict, orient='records')})

print(type(ndf))
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>

print(ndf)
OrderedDict([('myDataFrame', [OrderedDict([('A', 1), ('B', 'a')]), OrderedDict([('A', 2), ('B', 'b')]), OrderedDict([('A', 3), ('B', 'c')])])])
```

Comment: So, there is no option of having an OrderedDict being 'records'. Am I right?

Comment: Nope! But, why you need ordered dict as output?

Comment: I updated my post with one more information

Comment: I am answering an exercise in which I'm asked to use to_dict() to give the answer to an OrderedDict and the way it should be ordered seems to be 'records'